# Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES with Ionic Start

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an Ionic project. I get the following error when trying to run `ionic start` in the terminal.

This is the error that I am getting when trying to run:

> Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/jamess/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/41/25'n denied, mkdir '/Users/james/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/55/43'

Answer (score 6):

Provide ownership to npm as

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Comment: Where do I find the group ?

Answer (score 0):

Run command with Sudo or change permission for that directory